How to resolve Invalid character value for cast specification. in SSIS 2016?
I have an SSIS package that writes data originating from a text file, into a staging table, and from staging table into a production table.  The flat file is fixed width format and so the second data flow task started with an OLEDB Source embedded with an SQL query comprised of substring functions.  I'm using Derived Column Transformation because many of the values are numeric in nature.  The field triggering the above error is defined as numeric(4,4).  I've also tried decimal(4,4) and reached the same error above.
The derived column expression is: (DT_Decimal,4)[MyField]
The errors received are:

Invalid character value for cast specification.


The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the
specified type.".

I tried re-directing rows to another flat file.  Of the total records, only 1 loaded into the database.  The rest of the rows were redirected to the flat file.
The first record below is being redirected while the second record is being loaded into the table.
01.0800
00.0000

How would I re-configure either the field in the database or the OLEDB Destination to ensure all rows are inserted?

The parameters to the decimal and numeric data types are the number of digits of precision and scale. A numeric(4,4) data type can hold four digits total and four digits after the decimal place. Consider how you might change those parameters to cater for the given inputs, e.g. db<>fiddle

@AlwaysLearning Thank you so much!!  I do not always create tables and lost perspective on the interpretation of precision and scale.  Appreciate your guidance!
